# Freemarker - default value for variable that may be missing or blank?

Tags: freemarker, trim, default-value

In Freemarker, I want to treat something that may be missing (not defined on given object or in given `Map`), have a `null` value, be an empty string `""` or a string with whitespace only (`" \t\n"`), AKA blank string. Or a real value like `"foo"`.

In case it's anything besides a non-blank string, I want the expression to return a default value.

How can I handle this in Freemarker?

So far, this is what I use:

```
${ obj.propery???then(obj.property?trim!"default") }
```

But I can imagine something more ellegant, like

```
${ obj.property!!?trim!"default" }
```

and even with trimming (which is quite common operation for templates):

```
${ obj.property!!!"default" }
```

Is there something such in Freemarker? (Besides coding my own method or macro.)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same challenge and came to this solution:

```
${ (obj.property!"")?trim }
```

It also trims the empty string but is easier to read than writing an function or a if.

Comment: doc reference: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_missing_default

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in FreeMarker for that, at least not in 2.3.24. I think the best way to address that is wiriting a `trimToNull` function, and then you can write `trimToNull(obj.property)!"default"` and `trimToNull(obj.property)??`, etc.