# Combine two freemarker hash with same key inside table

Tags: freemarker

My two hash/maps are as below. I want to get the value corresponding to the key from the first map and second map and then add them to table

Map 1
[
{
"key": "1",
"value":"Potato"
},
{
"key": "2",
"value":"Chilly"
}
]

Map 2
[
{
"key": "1",
"value":"Apple"
},
{
"key": "2",
"value":"Plum"
}
]

I want the data in the fashion so that I can fetch data for the same key from both the map at the same time

```
<#list map1+map2?keys as key>
<tr>
    <td>${key}</td>
    <td >${map1[key]}</td>
    <td >${map2[key]}</td>
</tr>
</#list>
```

I know I am doing something wrong, but not able to process the code. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parenthesize the map concatenation in order to be able to use the built-in `?keys`, so `(map1 + map2)?keys`. Also, you might want to check for empty values if the maps are not equal by suffixing your expression with `!"default value"`, or simply `!` if you want to have no default:

```
<#assign map1 = { "1": "Potato", "2": "Chilly" } >
<#assign map2 = { "1": "Apple", "2": "Plum", "3": "Extra" } >
<#list (map1 + map2)?keys as key>
<tr>
    <td>${key}</td>
    <td>${map1[key]!}</td>
    <td>${map2[key]!}</td>
</tr>
</#list>
```

See also:

- [Freemarker - default value for variable that may be missing or blank?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37035953/freemarker-default-value-for-variable-that-may-be-missing-or-blank)